# java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am on Kafka 0.9.0.0 and Spark version 1.5. While trying to read from kafka, I get the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
    at
```

Has anyone experienced this and how to fix it? Could it be because of some version incompatibility? I have see this before [Spark Streaming Kafka stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145483/spark-streaming-kafka-stream) so that is why I suspect version issues.

Comment: You can take a look here, it solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145483/spark-streaming-kafka-stream

Comment: Are you suggesting that Kafka 0.9 is incompatible with Spark 1.5?